# In React, onMouseEnter or hover is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, hover, mouseevent, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have one image with `opacity = 1` at the beginning.

When mouse enters the image, change `opacity = 0.5`. When mouse leaves the image, change the opacity back.

here is one code:

```
mouseEnter() {
    console.log('mouse enter')
    const classname = '.' + this.props.post.code
    document.querySelector(classname).classList.add('image-hover-opacity')
}

mouseLeave() {
    console.log('mouse leave')
    const classname = '.' + this.props.post.code
    document.querySelector(classname).classList.remove('image-hover-opacity')
}

    render() {
        <img src={src} onMouseEnter={::this.mouseEnter} onMouseLeave={::this.mouseLeave} />
    }
```

onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave are fired when mouse enters and leaves the image, respectively, good. But the problem is when I move the mouse inside the image, both onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave are fired.

And I have tried css solution as well, when I hover on image, change the opacity property. But the problem is the same: when I move mouse inside the image, :hover and not hover are fired multiple times.

How to solve this? thanks

---

**UPDATE**
There is something in my previous code. Created one [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BENLI522/69z2wepo/68737/), and it works.
sorry guys

Comment: [Can't reproduce it](http://jsbin.com/panege/edit?js,console,output). But for this stuff you should usually use CSS anyways, maybe show us more code?

Comment: Why don't you use CSS  `:hover{ opaclty:0.5 }` ?

Comment: @prosti I have tried the css way. But when I move the mouse inside the image, the opacity toggles between 0.5 and 1

Comment: @BenjaminLi, I updated the example it works.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using `document.querySelector` is not a very React way of thinking. You can try this approach:

- Use a `div` wrapping this `img` to avoid this weird mouseEnter behavior
- Use `this.state` with opacity

  ```
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }

  mouseEnter() {
      console.log('mouse enter')
      this.setState({opacity: 0.5})
  }

  mouseLeave() {
      console.log('mouse leave')
      this.setState({opacity: 1})
  }

      render() {
        <div style={{opacity: this.state.opacity}}>
          <img src={src} onMouseEnter={::this.mouseEnter} onMouseLeave={::this.mouseLeave} />
        </div>
      }
  ```

Answer (score 16):

I really think you can achieve this in CSS only.
So your component should have simple `className` property and that class should have the definitions for:

```
.image-hover-opacity:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }
    

  render() {
    return(
      <img className="image-hover-opacity" src="http://i.imgur.com/PLKabDV.png" />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.image-hover-opacity:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution I've found anywhere in the internet and thusly the most effective in terms of mantainability. Thank you!